# bs4 returns empty array when i try to scrape some elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello i am new to scraping ... i want to scrape from this page "https://xangle.io/project/XTZ/full-disclosure" this element:
[![this element][1]][1]..
(you need to scroll down to find this section)
But when i use the following codes it returns empty value
I have used the following code

```
def token_name_scraper(soup, section, class_):
token_name_container = soup.find_all(section, class_ = class_)
print(token_name_container)

#Build the scraper
def scraper(url):
    r1 = requests.get(url)
    coverpage = r1.content
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, 'html5lib')
    token_name_scraper(soup1, "div", "fv1")
scraper("https://xangle.io/project/XTZ/full-disclosure")
```

It returns empty array..Please Could aybody help me find the solution?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/shXR9.png

Comment: page you've shown in screenshot and page on link is different

Comment: if you scroll down you will find token profile

Comment: @SabbirTalukdar `JavaScript` is playing there! `requests` will not be able to render it. use `selenium` , just print `response.text` and you will understand what's going on

Comment: i did used selenium but maybe not the correct way, i will have a look and get back to you

Comment: should i print driver.response.text?

Comment: @SabbirTalukdar in selenium. you can use `driver.page_source`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211704/discussion-between-sabbir-talukdar-and--c).

Comment: hello are you there